# searchBar causes a shadow appear on the results

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, google-places-api

I am getting results from Google Places Autocomplete and showing them in the collectionView. Default cell color is white, and background is light blue and as I press the searchBar they become gray. Is there a way to change it?

[image]

Comment: Are you using UISearchController?

Comment: No, I am using UISearchBarDelegate

Comment: Probably you should set `obscuresBackgroundDuringPresentation` to `false` [More info](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uisearchcontroller/1618656-obscuresbackgroundduringpresenta?language=objc)

Comment: Yes! It works. Thanks a lot!

Comment: That property is on `UISearchController` which you said you weren't using?